# when git ,fatal: Unable to create '//Mac/Home/Desktop/TGh/02/.git/index.lock': File exists

Tags: git, github

fatal: Unable to create '//Mac/Home/Desktop/TGh/02/.git/index.lock': File exists.

[image]

Comment: Please add some more information to your question like in what context you are receiving this error message, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The error message tells you exactly what to do:

> ```
> If no other git process is currently running, this probably means a
> git process crashed in this repository earlier. Make sure no other git
> process is running and remove the file manually to continue.
> ```

So, stop any running Git processes you may have (close Source Tree, Xcode, etc), and simply remove the lock file manually, and carry on.